# Reading from SQL Server with params: pandas (or pyodbc) not functioning properly

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pandas, pyodbc

I'm using a query in SQL Server that requires a range to check whether a number is in that range (e.g. in the below to check if `DemographicGroupDimID` is either (1,2 or 3) . After doing some googling the only way I found to be able to do that was the below:

## SQL

```
DECLARE @adults table (Id int)
INSERT INTO @adults VALUES (1), (2), (3)

SELECT [date], [station], [impression] = SUM([impressions]) / COUNT(DISTINCT [datetime] )
       FROM 
       (SELECT [datetime] = DATEADD(minute,td.Minute,DATEADD(hour,td.NielsenLocalHour,CONVERT(smalldatetime, ddt.DateKey))), [date] = ddt.DateKey, [station] = nd.Name, [impressions] = SUM(naf.Impression)
       FROM [Nielsen].[dbo].[NielsenAnalyticsFact] as naf
       LEFT JOIN [dbo].[DateDim] AS ddt
       ON naf.StartDateDimID = ddt.DateDimID
       LEFT JOIN [dbo].NetworkDim as nd
       ON naf.NetworkDimID = nd.NetworkDimID
       LEFT JOIN [dbo].TimeDim as td
       ON naf.QuarterHourDimID = td.TimeDimID
       WHERE (naf.NielsenMarketDimID = 1
                     AND naf.RecordTypeDimID = 2
                     AND naf.AudienceEstimateTypeDimID = 1
                     AND naf.DailyOrWeeklyDimID = 1
                     AND naf.RecordSequenceCodeDimID = 5
                     AND naf.ViewingTypeDimID = 4
                     AND naf.QuarterHourDimID IS NOT NULL
                     AND naf.DemographicGroupDimID < 31
                     AND nd.Affiliation = 'Cable'
                     AND naf.NetworkDimID != 1278
                     AND naf.DemographicGroupDimID in (SELECT Id FROM @adults))
       GROUP BY DATEADD(minute,td.Minute,DATEADD(hour,td.NielsenLocalHour,CONVERT(smalldatetime, ddt.DateKey))), nd.Name, ddt.DateKey) 
AS grouped_table
GROUP BY [date], [station]
ORDER BY [date], [station]
```

If I need to dynamically do this, with different ranges, this fails, like so:

## Pandas query

```
from queries import DB_CREDENTIALS
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

sql_ = """DECLARE @adults table (Id int)
INSERT INTO @adults VALUES ?

SELECT [date], [station], [impression] = SUM([impressions]) / COUNT(DISTINCT [datetime] )
       FROM
       (SELECT [datetime] = DATEADD(minute,td.Minute,DATEADD(hour,td.NielsenLocalHour,CONVERT(smalldatetime, ddt.DateKey))), [date] = ddt.DateKey, [station] = nd.Name, [impressions] = SUM(naf.Impression)
       FROM [Nielsen].[dbo].[NielsenAnalyticsFact] as naf
       LEFT JOIN [dbo].[DateDim] AS ddt
       ON naf.StartDateDimID = ddt.DateDimID
       LEFT JOIN [dbo].NetworkDim as nd
       ON naf.NetworkDimID = nd.NetworkDimID
       LEFT JOIN [dbo].TimeDim as td
       ON naf.QuarterHourDimID = td.TimeDimID
       WHERE (naf.NielsenMarketDimID = 1
                     AND naf.RecordTypeDimID = 2
                     AND naf.AudienceEstimateTypeDimID = 1
                     AND naf.DailyOrWeeklyDimID = 1
                     AND naf.RecordSequenceCodeDimID = 5
                     AND naf.ViewingTypeDimID = 4
                     AND naf.QuarterHourDimID IS NOT NULL
                     AND naf.DemographicGroupDimID < 31
                     AND nd.Affiliation = 'Cable'
                     AND naf.NetworkDimID != 1278
                     AND naf.DemographicGroupDimID in (SELECT Id FROM @adults))
       GROUP BY DATEADD(minute,td.Minute,DATEADD(hour,td.NielsenLocalHour,CONVERT(smalldatetime, ddt.DateKey))), nd.Name, ddt.DateKey)
AS grouped_table
GROUP BY [date], [station]
ORDER BY [date], [station]"""

with pyodbc.connect(DB_CREDENTIALS) as cnxn:
    df = pd.read_sql(sql=sql_, con=cnxn, params=['(30)'])
```

## The error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DatabaseError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-4b63847d007f> in <module>()
      1 with pyodbc.connect(DB_CREDENTIALS) as cnxn:
----> 2     df = pd.read_sql(sql=sql_, con=cnxn, params=['(30)'])

C:\Users\mburke\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda64\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.pyc in read_sql(sql, con, index_col, coerce_float, params, parse_dates, columns, chunksize)
    497             sql, index_col=index_col, params=params,
    498             coerce_float=coerce_float, parse_dates=parse_dates,
--> 499             chunksize=chunksize)
    500 
    501     try:

C:\Users\mburke\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda64\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.pyc in read_query(self, sql, index_col, coerce_float, params, parse_dates, chunksize)
   1593 
   1594         args = _convert_params(sql, params)
-> 1595         cursor = self.execute(*args)
   1596         columns = [col_desc[0] for col_desc in cursor.description]
   1597 

C:\Users\mburke\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda64\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.pyc in execute(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1570             ex = DatabaseError(
   1571                 "Execution failed on sql '%s': %s" % (args[0], exc))
-> 1572             raise_with_traceback(ex)
   1573 
   1574     @staticmethod

C:\Users\mburke\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda64\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.pyc in execute(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1558                 cur.execute(*args, **kwargs)
   1559             else:
-> 1560                 cur.execute(*args)
   1561             return cur
   1562         except Exception as exc:

DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'DECLARE @adults table (Id int)
INSERT INTO @adults VALUES ?

SELECT [date], [station], [impression] = SUM([impressions]) / COUNT(DISTINCT [datetime] )
       FROM
       (SELECT [datetime] = DATEADD(minute,td.Minute,DATEADD(hour,td.NielsenLocalHour,CONVERT(smalldatetime, ddt.DateKey))), [date] = ddt.DateKey, [station] = nd.Name, [impressions] = SUM(naf.Impression)
       FROM [Nielsen].[dbo].[NielsenAnalyticsFact] as naf
       LEFT JOIN [dbo].[DateDim] AS ddt
       ON naf.StartDateDimID = ddt.DateDimID
       LEFT JOIN [dbo].NetworkDim as nd
       ON naf.NetworkDimID = nd.NetworkDimID
       LEFT JOIN [dbo].TimeDim as td
       ON naf.QuarterHourDimID = td.TimeDimID
       WHERE (naf.NielsenMarketDimID = 1
                     AND naf.RecordTypeDimID = 2
                     AND naf.AudienceEstimateTypeDimID = 1
                     AND naf.DailyOrWeeklyDimID = 1
                     AND naf.RecordSequenceCodeDimID = 5
                     AND naf.ViewingTypeDimID = 4
                     AND naf.QuarterHourDimID IS NOT NULL
                     AND naf.DemographicGroupDimID < 31
                     AND nd.Affiliation = 'Cable'
                     AND naf.NetworkDimID != 1278
                     AND naf.DemographicGroupDimID in (SELECT Id FROM @adults))
       GROUP BY DATEADD(minute,td.Minute,DATEADD(hour,td.NielsenLocalHour,CONVERT(smalldatetime, ddt.DateKey))), nd.Name, ddt.DateKey)
AS grouped_table
GROUP BY [date], [station]
ORDER BY [date], [station]': ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '@P1'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)")
```

Is this because the declare statement needs to be within the bounds of the select statement itself? I'm not sure how `pandas` handles the `pyodbc` cursor object so I'm unsure where this error stems from.

Edit: Just to note, the param I passed in this instance was `(30)` just to use the simple case of when there is only one number in the range which fails. It of course also fails for more complex strings like `(1), (2), (3)` as was the case with the example above.

Comment: An additional note: this query works fine if the param is replaced with the actual value. So perhaps a workaround would be to just dynamically format the SQL query string itself.

Comment: Two things: 1) why not use SQL's `IN(?, ?, ?)` clause if passing a handful of integer scalars; or 2) why not call a stored procedure passing in params?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use [prepared statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) in your SQL, you can't put multiple values for one placeholder/parameter/bind variable!

Beside this you can use placeholders/parameters/bind variables only in place of [literals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literal_(computer_programming)), you can't use it for part of SQL statement which is *not* a literal.

In your case you tried to put `(` and `)` which is part of SQL, but **not** a literal as parameters.

Using parameters/prepared statements/bind variable will also protect you from some SQL injections.

that said, try to change your code as follows:

change

```
INSERT INTO @adults VALUES ?
```

to

```
INSERT INTO @adults VALUES (?)
```

and

```
df = pd.read_sql(sql=sql_, con=cnxn, params=['(30)'])
```

to

```
df = pd.read_sql(sql=sql_, con=cnxn, params=['30'])
```

**UPDATE:**

you can prepare your SQL this way:

```
In [9]: vals = [20,30,40]

In [32]: vals
Out[32]: [20, 30, 40]

In [33]: ' (?)' * len(vals)
Out[33]: ' (?) (?) (?)'
```

then:

```
In [14]: sql_ = """DECLARE @adults table (Id int)
   ....: INSERT INTO @adults VALUES {}
   ....:
   ....: SELECT [date],
   ....: """

In [15]: sql_.format(' (?)' * len(vals))
Out[15]: 'DECLARE @adults table (Id int)\nINSERT INTO @adults VALUES (?) (?) (?)\n\nSELECT [date],\n'
```

Pay attention at generated `(?) (?) (?)`

and finally call your SQL:

```
df = pd.read_sql(sql=sql_.format(' (?)' * len(vals)), con=cnxn, params=vals)
```

Comment: but this only works in the case where i have one value right? for instance what if i needed to pass 4 values, [1,2,3,4]? would i need to alter the `sql_` to be `VALUES (?), (?), (?), (?)`? also i don't follow your last two sentences (or perhaps misunderstand the role of the `VALUES` statement) could you explain what you mean by "only for literals", implying a string is not a literal? thanks again!

Comment: thanks max, yeah, that's what i figured had to be done. but i wasn't sure if maybe i was misusing params or if it was a bug in pandas.

Comment: i've accepted your answer max, but I think the question still remains, is this expected behavior in pandas/pyodbc or is this a bug.

Comment: @mburke05, it's __not__ a bug, it's an expected behavior! Any DB system  wants to know how many parameters/bind variables/etc. will you provide. Search for `prepared statements` in internet for details... For example: read [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement)